# Log4j SyslogAppender not attempting a connection

Tags: tomcat, log4j

I have an application that uses log4j to write log files.  I don't have access to the source code, but I can assume that if I create an appender in the log4j.xml file that it should use that appender without needing a code change.

Currently I can confirm that no packets are being generated from the system to the remote syslog server via wireshark.  I can telnet to the remote syslog server on port 514 and write messages without an issue.  I can assume that something isn't right with my XML, but I have no messages to tell me what the error is.

Here's the Appender:

```
<appender name="SYSLOG" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender">
    <param name="Facility" value="USER" /> 
    <param name="syslogHost" value="172.16.81.39:514" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" /> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}][%5p](%t) %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

I have also tried the Log4j 2 syntax

```
<appender name="syslog" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender">
    <param name="format" value="bsd" />
    <param name="host" value="172.16.81.39" />
    <param name="port" value="514" />
    <param name="protocol" value="TCP" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}][%5p](%t) %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Here's the corresponding Logger:

```
<logger name="printing.com.application" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG" />
</logger>
```

If I change the `<appender-ref />` to the default PRINTING_MONTHLY_ROLL then it will print to the log file.

---

EDIT: Still stumped but I'll add some more info on my problem

1: If I rename the default `PRINTING_MONTHLY_ROLL` to `SYSLOG` then the messages are correctly output to the log file

2: If I give the logger a bogus name then I see log4j init error messages in the system log

3: If I give the syslog appender an incorrect host parameter, it will give me an error that the host could not be found and that logging will fail.  Since I do not get this message after saving the config listed in my original question, I can only assume that there are no errors with the syntax.

4: Firewalls on either side are not an issue.  I can make a connection with telnet and I confirmed that port TCP:514 is allowed on both sides in the proper direction.

Comment: did you try a simple filelog or console log appender to see that your configuration changes applies?

Comment: Yes.  The changes are applied.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same behavior, the Syslog appender does not try to connect, if i stop and restart the application several times sometime it log correctly but mostly not, so I think this is a bug in the Syslog appender

--- UPDATE ---

In my case I've just found that the problems was about DNS resolution, try to disable the DNS resolution for messages coming from remote hosts in your rsyslogd configuration, in ubuntu on an arm device I've found the option in /etc/default/rsyslog

```
# Options for rsyslogd
# -x disables DNS lookups for remote messages
# See rsyslogd(8) for more details
RSYSLOGD_OPTIONS="-x"
```